# How to use the Instagram api on ios to post on Facebook if the accounts are linked on Instagram and Facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, api, instagram-api

I am developing an iOS app using swift and I am logging in using Instagram API. On Instagram, users can link their Facebook accounts. If I post to Instagram from my app, is the post published on Facebook if Instagram and Facebook are linked?

If not, is there a way to use something like a "single sign on" in my app for users that are using Instagram with a Facebook login? My goal is to be able to retrieve and publish info from/to both using the access token retrieved from Instagram.

Comment: there is no API to post

Comment: is there a way to do what I asked? It's only about posts.. it's also about retrieving info. Can I have one login for both?